# How to solve this error Cannot destructure property 'getFieldDecorator' of 'this.props.form' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a class based components in React, My code looks ok but even though it is showing some syntax error like this. --> Cannot destructure property 'getFieldDecorator' of 'this.props.form' as it is undefined.

So please help me how to resolve this issue

This is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Form, Input, Button, Card, DatePicker, } from "antd";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <div>
        <Card>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
            <Form.Item>
              {getFieldDecorator("roomno", {
                // initialValue: keyData && keyData.room_no,
                rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input your room no!" }],
              })(
                <Input
                  name="roomNumber"
                  style={{ width: 300 }}
                  placeholder="Room No"
                />,
              )}
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item>
              {getFieldDecorator("date-picker1", {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input your Checkin date" }],
              })(<DatePicker placeholder="Checkin date" style={{ width: 300 }} />)
              }
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item>
              {getFieldDecorator("date-picker2", {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input your Checkout date" }],
              })(<DatePicker placeholder="Checkout date" style={{ width: 300 }} />)
              }
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item>

              {getFieldDecorator("noOfKeys", {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input your key!" }],
              })(
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  style={{ width: 300 }}
                  placeholder="No of Keys"
                />,
              )}
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item>
              <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
        </Card>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: at the very 1st render this.props does not have any value that's why you are seeing `Cannot destructure property 'getFieldDecorator' of 'this.props.form' as it is undefined.` just check this.props have form value before destructuring

Comment: As a piece of advice, you can search for code on GitHub: https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=getFieldDecorator&type=Code

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using code that should be in its own Form component. You are trying to get `getFieldDecorator` from `this.props.form`. But your `App` doesn't have properties because it's the root of your application.

So you need to create a custom Form component instead, and use `Form.create()` when exporting your component.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/amrakun/front-ot/blob/17c3bd0f1ea29a765a110c8a0473bfdbc5c0fc75/src/modules/settings/components/users/UserForm.js) for example.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button, Card, DatePicker } from "antd";

class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <div>
        <Card>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
            <Form.Item>
              {getFieldDecorator("roomno", {
                // initialValue: keyData && keyData.room_no,
                rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input your room no!" }],
              })(
                <Input
                  name="roomNumber"
                  style={{ width: 300 }}
                  placeholder="Room No"
                />,
              )}
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item>
              {getFieldDecorator("date-picker1", {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input your Checkin date" }],
              })(<DatePicker placeholder="Checkin date" style={{ width: 300 }} />)
              }
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item>
              {getFieldDecorator("date-picker2", {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input your Checkout date" }],
              })(<DatePicker placeholder="Checkout date" style={{ width: 300 }} />)
              }
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item>

              {getFieldDecorator("noOfKeys", {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input your key!" }],
              })(
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  style={{ width: 300 }}
                  placeholder="No of Keys"
                />,
              )}
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item>
              <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
        </Card>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

LoginForm.propTypes = propTypes;

export default Form.create()(LoginForm);
```

Comment: Hi @Drarig29, I tried your code it is saying like this